# Is there a formula to know what is for example the 11th element of a variation list with knowing the k and n and digits?

Tags: probability

We could have 27 different 3-digit numbers from 3 different digits. Is there any formula we could use to find for example what the 11th 3-digit is without generating all the possible variations and looking up the index? (k=3, n=3)

For example, in this list, how to know 11th number is 212?

111
112
113
121
122
123
131
132
133
211
212  ----> 11th number
213
221
222
223
231
232
233
311
312
313
321
322
323
331
332
333

Comment: Why do we have 111 through 113 twice?

Comment: @KotaMori mistype sorry thanks for mentioning.

Comment: What ordering are you assuming?  Lexicographic, as shown?  If so, the solution is equivalent to converting $11-1$ in base $10$ to $101$ in base $3$ and augmenting all resulting digits by $1.$  I'm confident you can find the answer to that on [math.SE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier to see this pattern if we label them in a slightly different manner:

```
000 : 0
001 : 1
002 : 2
010 : 3
011 : 4
...
222 : 26
```

On the left side is your label with each digit subtracted by one.
On the right side is the ordering starting at zero.

This is identical to the mapping between ternary and decimal number representations.

So, if we want to know 11th number, we first convert 10 ($11-1$) to ternary representation. Since $10 = 3^2 + 1$, $101$ is the ternary representation for 10.  Finally, to convert this to your label, we add one to each digit, i.e. $212$.

Comment: thanks. what if instead of 3 types of digits we have 4, and digits are 2, 9, 5, 7? what would be the 3-digit number of 20th index?

Comment: $19 = 4^2 + 3 = 103 (4)$. Then you map digits (0,1,2,3) --> (2,9,5,7) respectively. So the answer would be 927?

Comment: Thanks a lot. What if all the permutations have one and only one repetition? In that case, how does indexing for such permutation with limited repetition works? Like for example: 5997 or 2952 or 7795.

Comment: That will be a very different question.  You should open a new thread with a detailed description.

Comment: You may know the answer to this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4247472/permutations-with-global-limited-repetition-without-the-need-for-providing-digit